# No space between *gettext* string and cursor of *read* command

Tags: bash, gettext

Say the following *Bash* script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export TEXTDOMAINDIR=./locale
export TEXTDOMAIN=test-gettext-read
. gettext.sh

echo -n $(gettext "Insert a word: ")
read word
```

*GNU gettext* is used to make the string translatable and *read* is used to get user input. However, even if there's a trailing space in the *gettext* message, there's no space in the terminal when I run the script. Example (cursor is `|`):

```
$ bash test-gettext-read.sh
Insert a word:|
```

As a workaround, I remove the trailing space in the *gettext* string and I add a space outside:

```
echo -n $(gettext "Insert a word:")" "
```

Then it works:

```
$ bash test-gettext-read.sh
Insert a word: |
```

My question: is there a better workaround?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use `echo -n`.

Simply do this:

```
gettext "Insert a word: "
read word
```

Or you could wrap your expression whit quotes and then pass it to echo:

```
echo -ne "$(gettext 'Insert\ta\tword: ')"
```

Using quotes will ensure that the result passed to echo will be interpreted as one parameter `"Insert a word: "` insteand of 3: `'Insert'` `'a'` `'word:'`.

Comment: Thanks, but I realize that my example is not complete. What about `echo -en $(gettext "a\tb: ")`? If I use the syntax `gettext -e "a\tb: "`, I'll not be able to get translatable strings with `xgettext -j -o locale/test-gettext-read.pot --from-code=UTF-8 -L shell test-gettext-read.sh`.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that `xgettext` only extracts the first argument of `gettext`, so I used to write `echo -ARGUMENTS $(gettext "string")`.

Comment: @jpfleury I changed my post to offer you a solution using the echo.